# Как работает поиск без полных совпадений?

Tags: c#, поиск

У меня есть запись, она имеет несколько полей, к примеру: город, имя, фамилия, биография и т.д. Как сделать поиск который бы искал не при полном совпадении - когда находим запись полностю введя к примеру Иван, а если еще вводя - ив и похожие показать. Так к примеру ищет Google, как оно работает и сложно ли сделать подобное в обычной программе, запись в C# колекции
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запись у Вас где? если в БД, то для Вашей задачи подойдет выборка с  предикатом LIKE. Если в коллекции - ручной фильтр, например, через регулярные выражения.

Comment: Не знаю всех хитростей данного механизма, но у нас на проекте механизм поиска реализован внутри базы данных с помощью таких функций как `LIKE` и `ILIKE`. Они позволяют по частичному имени искать совпадения с помощью регулярных выражений

Comment: Добавлю ещё: ищите по термину autocomplete.В WinForms и WPF есть встроенное автодополнение. Возможно, именно это вам надо.

Comment: @МаксЖуков обновил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть набор строк, содержащих фразы или предложения.

Нужно заранее знать, сколько минимум результатов вы хотите получить, например 10.

0. Самое простое решение для вас - это поиск по вхождению, то есть если в строке найден фрагмент, введенный в поисковом запросе, то строку можно считать найденной
1. Найденные выше строки можно отсортировать по следующим весам, если вхождение в начале строки +2 балла, если вхождение в начале слова +1 балл, опционально можно сложить все вхождения, но тогда по поисковому запросу `ив` - строка `Иванов Иван Иванович из деревни Ивантеевка` всегда будет на первом месте
2. Если количество выше найденных результатов меньше 10, то отрезаем от поискового запроса символ справа и повторяем шаги 0 и 1.
3. Если количество выше найденных результатов меньше 10, то отрезаем символ слева и повторяем шаги 0, 1 и 2
4. Повторяем шаги 0-3, пока: количество результатов выдачи не достигнет 10 ИЛИ поисковый запрос стал содержать 1 символ ИЛИ количество результатов выдачи равно общему количеству записей в базе, но меньше 10.

Усложняющие алгоритмы:

1. Разбить поисковый запрос на слова, повторять выше показанный алгоритм для каждого слова, по одному шагу от последнего слова к первому.
2. Дополнительное ранжирование по суммарному количеству вхождений и вхождению полной фразы улучшит качество поисковой выдачи.

Чтобы сделать красиво, можно подсвечивать вхождения в результирующей выдаче - массив из пар `(индекс символа, длина)`.

Собственно, дальше это всё можно развивать столько, насколько фантазии хватит, но никаких космических секретов я вам не раскрыл, и понятия не имею, как оно там в Гугле или Яндексе работает.
<sup>(но это не точно)</sup>

*Кстати, всю эту красивую историю можно реализовать на базе Stored Procedure прямо в БД, если у вас есть конечно БД.*

Comment: Поисковики ещё могут учитывать популярные запросы поиска в данном регионе, историю поисков данного пользователя и многое другое. Если в указанных сущностях есть что-то подходящее, то вес этих вариантов в выдаче повышается.

Comment: @CrazyElf ой, что касается популярных запросов, то там настолько крутая оптимизация, что даже поисковые боты чаще переходят по ссылкам, попадающим в популярную зону, чем по остальным.